# Delayed Job executes with wrong data when I have a big amount of jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, delayed-job, medical

I read a lot and I saw that Delayed Job doesn't actually use serialized data but it retrieves information using the deserialized id.

This isn't the behavior that I was expected when I choose that gem, but I can deal with it.
The real problem is that I use DJ to fire some alerts based on some data using an after_save callback and sometimes that data fires the alert too much in the future. So basically if I save three times the medical result for different reasons and the third time finalizes it, I will fire three alerts because DJ works three times on the finalized result.

Does exist a way to enqueue a job in the same queue, for the same method just once? I saw that handler isn't exposed and `handle_asyncronously` doesn't accept a parameter to identify the process.

The best solution would have been to work directly on serialized data but also execute it once is acceptable.

Thank you in advance!